# Code for date formatting not executed but shown in output

Tags: php, date, mysqli

I've tried to fix this for the last 10 minutes without any luck.

First I had the following code, which was working perfectly fine:

```
<?php echo date(d-m-Y - H:i:s , '.$stt["post_timestamp"].'); ?>
```

Since I added a check whether the field is empty, I changed it into:

```
echo '<div class="showTicket get created_on">date(d-m-Y - H:i:s , '.$stt["post_timestamp"].');</div>';
```

It currently outputs it as: `date(d-m-Y - H:i:s , 1391881470);` while it should output it like before: `08-02-2014 - 14:17:42` (this is the timestamp).

I also tried:

```
$ts_date = date(d-m-Y);
$ts_time = date(H:i:s);

echo '<div class="showTicket get created_on">'.$ts_date.'-'.$ts_time.' , '.$stt["post_timestamp"].');</div>';
```

But that doesn't working either. Long story short: I need to have the correct format for:

```
echo '<div class="showTicket get created_on">date(d-m-Y - H:i:s , '.$stt["post_timestamp"].');</div>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<div class="showTicket get created_on">' . date('d-m-Y - H:i:s', $stt["post_timestamp"]) . '</div>';
```

Comment: Oh lord, I see what I've forgot. It's working perfectly fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you put quotes around $stt["post_timestamp"]?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo '<div class="showTicket get created_on">';
echo date("d-m-Y - H:i:s" , $stt["post_timestamp"]);
echo '</div>';
```

Basicaly your echo will output whatever is within its quote, so make sure you separe the html from your code. you could also have only one echo and concatanate your code like so :

```
echo '<div class="showTicket get created_on">' .date("d-m-Y - H:i:s" , $stt["post_timestamp"]) . '</div>';
```

edit : I have made this code as it is considering you said your first code line worked fine, although I'm pretty sure you should no quote the $stt variable. I've edited my initial post so it could come out alright

Comment: puzzled with the quotes as well, should be `date('d-m-Y - H:i:s', ...`

Comment: Ye thats my edit, i'm just trying to show that it should not work that way although OP seems to think it does